# Laravel file upload just uploads .tmp file

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, image-uploading

For some reason this did not work in my view:

```
{!! Form::open(['url'=>'notes','file'=>true]) !!}
```

So I just used this which seemed to get me a little further:

```
{!! Form::open(['url'=>'notes','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']) !!}
```

In the store method of my `PostsController` I have the following:

```
    $file = Input::file('picture');
    $file->move(public_path(). /pictures/');
```

When I try uploading the .jpeg file, a .tmp file gets uploaded into the right folder but its just a .tmp file that says :

> "The file cannot be displayed in the editor because it is either
>   binary, very large or uses and unsupported text encoding."

Not sure why its not uploading the `.jpeg` file itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to try this one

```
$file = Input::file('picture');
$destinationPath = public_path(). '/pictures/';
$filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();

Input::file('picture')->move($destinationPath, $filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        if ($request->file('photo')) {
        $destinationPath = "packages/.../img/media/";

        if (!is_dir($destinationPath)) {
            mkdir($destinationPath, 0777, true);
        }
        $final_location = $destinationPath . "/";
        $request->file('photo')
        ->move($final_location, filename.'.'. $request->file('photo')
        ->getClientOriginalExtension());
        }
```